# Get remote server uptime in hda application

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, hta

I'm able to ping remote servers by using the following code:

```
function ping(server) {
 var objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:").Get("Win32_PingStatus.Address='" + server + "'");
  $("#myInfo").html("<div><b>" + server + ":</b></div> \
                     <div>IP: " + objPing.ProtocolAddress + "</div> \
                 <div>Time to resolve: " + objPing.ResponseTime + "ms</div>");
    }
```

I'm trying to also get the remote server uptime by adding:
    var objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\" + server + "\root\cimv2")

Once I get that working I'll be able to query the server and get the uptime. In vbs the code would look like the following but I need it to work in my hta application and not as vbs:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & server & "\root\cimv2")
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * From Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System")

For Each objOS in colOperatingSystems
intSystemUptime = Int(objOS.SystemUpTime / 60 / 60)
Wscript.Echo intSystemUptime & " hours"
Next
```

To add to this, I also included scripting in my hta application that launches putty on click. The solution I found to that function was to escape the backspaces. A snip it of that function looks like the following:

```
WshShell.Run('"C:/\Program Files (x86)/\Putty/\putty.exe" -ssh ' + server);
```

So I thought escaping might help like this but I'm still getting an error:

```
var objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:/\/\" + server + "/\root/\cimv2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quick googling turned up [this page](http://wmiplanet.blogspot.ch/2011/07/javascript-wmi-example-using-execquery.html) according to which something like this should work:

```
var server = "."

var locator = new ActiveXObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
var svc = locator.ConnectServer(server, "/root/cimv2");
svc.Security_.AuthenticationLevel = 0;
svc.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = 3;

var qry = "SELECT SystemUptime FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System";
var data = new Enumerator(svc.ExecQuery(qry));
for (;!data.atEnd();data.moveNext()) {
  var counters = new Enumerator(data.item().Properties_);
  for (;!counters.atEnd();counters.moveNext()) {
    WScript.Echo(counters.item().Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!!! Except WScript.Echo won't work in js so I made it a variable and appended the div I wanted it in. Thank you SO much!